# How to rename the column Item Child Count in a list (SharePoint)

Tags: site-column

I have a document library with an OOTB column called Item Child Count. Is there anyway I can change the name of this column? Or at least create an alias?

Comment: These columns do not seem to be appearing in my columns list to modify... I can only select when modifying my list view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the display name of the column? if Yes then you can easily do that by going to the list/document library  setting page and clicking on the column name you wish to change. This will navigate you to the column properties page where you can change the display name.
If you are referring to the internal name then you would need to update the respective column definition via feature.